# How to suppress the warning "Assignment within conditional. Did you mean == instead of =?"

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-warnings

With the new ASC 2.0 compiler I get warnings when I code like below:

```
// (_achievementsFromServer is an Array)
while(item=_achievementsFromServer.pop())
{
    // do something with item here
}
```

The warning reads: `"Assignment within conditional.  Did you mean == instead of =?"`
While in general I appreciate all warnings from the compiler, I'd like to suppress this one in this case because I did **not** mean `==` here. I want to pop all items in the array and do something with it until the array is empty.

```
while( (item=_achievementsFromServer.pop())==true )
```

seems to work but looks a bit confusing. Any other ideas?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator,   I think `while( (item=_achievementsFromServer.pop())==true )` is good not so confusing

Comment: I would think that != null would be better than == true. However, just wrapping it in parentheses without comparing it to anything would probably work.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship the compiler doesn't get fooled by more parentheses. But !=null is better indeed.

Comment: It's possible that an assignment from `pop()` could return `undefined`, in which case `!= null` wouldn't work. However, `Boolean(item = array.pop())` does the trick and silences the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was hoping for some other way, I think @AmyBlankenship improved my own suggestion:

```
while((item=_achievementsFromServer.pop())!=null)
{
    //....
}
```

It's clear and understandable what's going on, and doesn't rely on checking the length of the Array on every iteration.

Googling some more I found a compiler option `-compiler.warn-assignment-within-conditional` that could be set to `false` but then you won't be warned anywhere in your project anymore. And I'm not so confident that I never accidently type `=` instead of `==`, so that's not a good solution I think.

Comment: The only thing with this though, is you're not assigning the "popped" result to any variable, so you can't actually do anything with it in the while-loop (ex: call a "destroy()" method on each objects or something).

Answer (score 1):

This may seem better.

```
while(_achievementsFromServer.length > 0) {
    var item:Object = _achievementsFromServer.pop();
}
```

Just like removeChild

```
var d:DisplayObjectContainer;

while(d.numChildren > 0) {
    d.removeChildAt(0);
}
```